# How to format numbers stored in table to crore & lacs (Indian numbering system) in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have numbers stored in table such as 11000000, 7000000
and I want to convert them to 1.1 Crore, 70 lacs etc. ([Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)) and display them on aspx (UI)page.

Is there any way to format the numbers?

I have written following c# function in .cs file

```
public static int  CustomFormat(int budget)
{
    if (budget >= 10000000)
    {
        budget = Int32.Parse(((budget / 10000000) + "Cr").ToString());
    }
    else if (budget >= 100000)
    {
        budget = Int32.Parse(((budget / 100000) + "Lacs").ToString().Trim());
    }
    return budget;
}
```

which will be called from .aspx (UI) page like this :

```
<%# CustomFormat(Int32.Parse(Eval("budget").ToString())) %>
```

but it's showing following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Show what you have done, and where you have encountered difficulties.

Comment: i have edited the question, please check

Comment: you're passing a string containing text (e.g. "10000Cr") to Int32.Parse, which clearly won't work. I don't think Int32.Parse is even necessary here. And if you want fractions (e.g. 1.1 as you mentioned) then converting them to an int will not help with that, either.

Comment: @ADyson if i remove Int32.Parse it will give an error saying that can't implicitly convert type string to int

Comment: That's because you're trying to return an int from your function, but you need to return a string if you want the text included. Hang on, I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @ADyson Yes. I am waiting for the solution provided by you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here:

1) In your UI: `Int32.Parse(Eval("budget").ToString())` 
Here you appear to take an int (budget), convert it to a string, then instantly convert it back to an int again. As far as I can see this is completely redundant.

2) You're passing a string containing text (e.g. "10000Cr") to Int32.Parse, which clearly won't work. I don't think Int32.Parse is even necessary here. And if you want fractions (e.g. 1.1 as you mentioned) then converting them to an int will not help with that, either. You need a `float`.

3) You want a piece of formatted text including the "Cr" or "Lacs" phrases, but your function returns an `int` which cannot include this. It needs to return a `string`.

This should work I think (I can't test it right now):

```
public static string  CustomFormat(float budget)
{
    string budgetString = "";

    if (budget >= 10000000)
    {
        budgetString = (budget / 10000000) + "Cr";
    }
    else if (budget >= 100000)
    {
        budgetString = (budget / 100000) + "Lacs";
    }
    return budgetString;
}
```

And in the UI:

```
<%# CustomFormat(Eval("budget")) %>
```

Comment: Worked after doing this: 
   CustomFormat(Int32.Parse(Eval("budget").ToString()))  

Thanks for the solution!

Comment: But it's not showing 1.1 Cr for 11000000, it's showing only 1 cr

Comment: to get fractions such as 1.1, we can simply change the input type of the function to `float`. I have amended the answer. As for needing `(Int32.Parse(Eval("budget").ToString())`, you should not need it, especially not now the function is accepting a float. What is the original type of the "budget" variable here? If it's already a `float` you can just pass it directly to the function without all this backwards-and-forwards conversion.